# I'm having a problem with a Github Page app that runs fine on Glitch.me.I wante

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I wanted to have a simple chat-app as sort of a test for Java and also to make an easy way to message people, and as I learned more about Java as a whole I'd build off of it.
It ran completely fine on Glitch.com, however, it doesn't seem to be running at all off of Github Pages.

I would appreciate it if anyone could look through the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
https://github.com/wyrdagathr/chatroom/
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"doesn't seem to be running at all" is not a sufficiently clear description for anyone to be able to help you.

1. What are the steps you take to encounter the problem? What specific URL to visit, what to click on, what to type, etc
2. What is the problematic behavior? What specific thing are you seeing happen, or does no change to the screen happen whatsoever?
3. What do you expect to happen instead? What specific change to the screen do you expect to happen, or do you expect nothing to happen whatsoever?